# radio buttons request issue with jsp (maybe array is the solution?)

Tags: jsp, radio-button

I'm sorry for my formulation, but I don't quite know how to explain in one sentence. My Problem is:

I have a list of users displayed and you can grant them rights via clicking radio buttons. Every user has an ID. Here is the schema:

```
Name    Admin    Publisher    No Rights

Paul     ( )       ( )            (x)
John     (x)       ( )            ( )
Lisa     ( )       (x)            ( )
```

I think you get it what I want. I have to update a database where the rights are saved. I don't really know how to do it. I tried the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="rightsForID1" id="1-admin" value="1-admin"></input>
<label for="1-admin">Admin</label>

<input type="radio" name="rightsForID1" id="1-publisher" value="1-publisher"></input>
<label for="1-publisher">Publisher</label>
```

and so on. But how do I evaluate the request? I don't know how much users are in the list neither do I know whether the list is continuous or not, e.g. there could be no user with the ID "5". Is there a way to put the clicked values **and** the user IDs in an array? Or maybe something different, I only want to get the clicked values and the user IDs.

Comment: Would roles to all users be assinged in single click?

Comment: You need to generate dynamic ids for radio-types based on the unique key of user in list, say userId.

Comment: @ParkashKumar: I could do that, but how do I evaluate the request then?

Comment: You will be getting an array of values in request based on the name of the field.

Comment: I think, I don't understand. If I have two inputs with ids "ID1-admin" and "ID2-admin". Will I get an array with the ids as index? Like a Map (referring to Java)? Like {ID1-admin: checked, ID2-admin: not checked}

Comment: No, you will get your submitted values for e.g. 3 radiobutton of Admin-type as [true, false, true] and based on index you can get value for particular user.

Comment: Could you give a code example? Maybe I am too deep in Christmas feelings to understand :-P

Comment: Wait till i for a sample code for you...

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: Following is just a sample code, modify as required!**

Supose you have a list of User like,

```
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

and your form(html / jsp) fields(radios) will be generated dynamically based on the iteration of userlist as,

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Admin</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
        <th>No Rights</th>
    <tr>

    <% for(User user : userList){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=user.getName() %></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="admin" id="<%=user.getUserId()%>-admin" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="publisher" id="<%=user.getUserId()%>-publisher" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="noRight" id="<%=user.getUserId()%>-noRight" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

And when will you submit your form / or send data through ajax to server, you can get values for your radios as:

```
String[] radioAdmin = request.getParameter("admin");
String[] radioPublisher = request.getParameter("publisher");
String[] radioNoRight = request.getParameter("noRight");
```

Make sure of NULL check here.

You will be getting arrays of boolean for selected / not selected radios index-wise.
Here, you again need to iterate list of Users and get value for radio-type as,

```
for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++){
    User user = userList.get(i); // Will get user object from list index-wise

    boolean isAdminRoleAssigned = Boolean.valueOf(radioAdmin[i]);
    boolean isPublisherRoleAssigned = Boolean.valueOf(radioPublisher[i]);
    boolean isNoRoleAssigned = Boolean.valueOf(radioNoRight[i]);

    // Do rest of your logic here for boolean values of radios for each user.
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I didn't know radio buttons worked like that. I will test it as soon as possible!

Comment: When completing this line "String[] radioAdmin = request.getParameter("admin");" eclipse says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]" 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is it maybe "request.getParameterValues("admin");" ?

Comment: Ok, so you can get this like,
String radioAdmin = request.getParameter("admin");
String[] radioAdminArray = radioAdmin.split(",");

Comment: Initially, it will be returning String values separated by comma, you first you need to get it in String then check if it is not NULL and then convert it to String array.

Comment: First: Sorry, I was on vacation so I couldn't answer. Then: I think there is still a problem. If I have users 1, 2 and 3 and I delete user 2, all the other user IDs will stay the same. So when I get the values of the radios I may have "true,false" but those are for users 1 and 3, not 1 and 2. I need to transmit the user ID, too. So I need something like "1:true,3:false" when getting the values of the radios.

Comment: Get only active users based on true/false bit from database. So, when any user is deleted, its not been getting in the list to render radios for it.

Comment: When a user is deleted he will not be in the list, because I get the list of users from the database.